# Why didn't the Fellowship help Gandalf when he faced the Balrog?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf, the-fellowship-of-the-ring, balrogs

During the events of the Bridge of Khazad-dûm, the Fellowship witness Gandalf facing the Balrog. When Gandalf falls, he's still hanging on the cliff. And when Frodo cries out to Gandalf, Boromir prevents Frodo from going to him. Why didn't the fellowship help Gandalf to get up?

Comment: Because they're all a bunch of wimps.

Comment: Should I (or anyone) tag or edit this so as to make clear that it is pertaining to the PJ version?

Comment: @can-ned_food yes

Comment: If nothing else, you'd think at least Legolas could spray some arrows from the distance in the heat of the moment even though it would be futile. You know, desperate times, desperate measures thing.

Comment: Didn't he tell them to fly, then called them fools?

Comment: Go read the passage again: your description of what took place is just plain wrong.  As for why they don't help, 1) There really isn't anything they can do; 2) Gandalf is holding the bridge in order to let the rest of the Fellowship escape and go on to (possibly) complete the mission.

Comment: Because he's an experience hog and you don't want to put up with a maia after you *"steal"* some XP from him...

Comment: In most cases stealing a kill is a big NO, it is not respectful to do so.

Comment: @jamesqf As can-ned_food points out, the description is accurate for the Peter Jackson movie. Of course, I have no objections to you telling *Peter Jackson* to reread the text, but unfortunately it's a little late for that....

Comment: @Kyle Strand: But it's well-known that any logic or internal consistency in those movies is sheer accident.  Everthing else depends only on what that person thought would make good visuals, and not break the special effects budget.  If someone wants to ask a question specifically about the movie, they could attach a "movie" tag; that way I could ignore it :-)

Comment: @jamesqf I proposed that as an edit before writing my comment, actually, but apparently it hasn't been approved (not sure if it was rejected yet).

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but there was a Balrog there....

Comment: No frickin way I am taking on a balrog. I will leave that to the Ainur wizard guy.

Comment: Union rules. "Sorry, buddy, but the union sez I ain't s'posed to fight no supernatural creatures in an underground labyrinthy kind of place, or else someone's gonna file a grievance and then there's gonna be no end to it. So, hey, y'know, best of luck and all...and watch out, 'cuz that bridge there don't look like it's up to code, y'know? You should call the Mason's Union, have someone take a look at it, and...whoops. Well, there you are. Just goes to show, I guess. Hey, 's there anyplace to get a beer around here, d'ya think..?"

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In the [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring), the events played out slightly differently. Gandalf was already at the rear of the pack. The Hobbits, Gimli and Legolas had already made it to the arch when the Balrog appeared. They stayed inside the arch (obeying Gandalf) whereas the humans, Aragorn and Boromir decided to stand with Gandalf.

> *'Over the bridge!' cried Gandalf, recalling his strength. `Fly! This
>   is a foe beyond any of you. I must hold the narrow way. Fly! ' **Aragorn
>   and Boromir did not heed the command, but still held their ground,
>   side by side, behind Gandalf at the far end of the bridge.** The others
>   halted just within the doorway at the hall's end, and turned, unable
>   to leave their leader to face the enemy alone.*

Gandalf seems to have taken a few steps forward to attack the Balrog and in doing so, he caused the bridge to break. His companions (who at that point were about 10-15 feet behind him) were forced to run away, lest they fall into the chasm.

When he actually fell, it was over within seconds.

> *With a bound the Balrog leaped full upon the bridge. Its whip whirled and hissed.
>
>   'He cannot stand alone! ' cried Aragorn suddenly and ran back along the bridge. ' Elendil! ' he shouted. 'I am with you, Gandalf!'
>
>   `Gondor! ' cried Boromir and leaped after him.
>
>   At that moment Gandalf lifted his staff, and crying aloud he smote the bridge before him. The staff broke asunder and fell from his hand. A blinding sheet of white flame sprang up. The bridge cracked. Right at the Balrog's feet it broke, and the stone upon which it stood crashed into the gulf, while the rest remained, poised, quivering like a tongue of rock thrust out into emptiness.*
>
> *With a terrible cry the Balrog fell forward, and its shadow plunged
>   down and vanished. But even as it fell it swung its whip, and the
>   thongs lashed and curled about the wizard's knees, dragging him to the
>   brink. He staggered and fell, grasped vainly at the stone, and slid
>   into the abyss. 'Fly, you fools! ' he cried, and was gone.*
>
> *The fires went out, and blank darkness fell. The Company stood rooted
>   with horror staring into the pit. Even as Aragorn and Boromir came
>   flying back, the rest of the bridge cracked and fell. With a cry
>   Aragorn roused them.*

Comment: I like the idea that Gandalf recognizes how useless the rest of the fellowship would be against the Balrog. I feel that Gandalf was, at best, buying time or stalling with the intention of running or fighting to the death. I also feel like the battle between the Balrog and Gandalf would have been EPIC. Epic to to  the point that the others would become collateral damage. From a story telling point of view, I love that the battle was left up to the imagination of the reader as it leaves Gandalf and the Balrog's abilities open, and the battle as well.

Comment: @Josafoot - in the novel the Balrog is also a far more realistic and manageable size, not a hundred foot high lava monster.

Comment: I'll also note, that it seems to me that a straightforward reading would indicate that Gandalf's cry, "Fly, you fools!" may have been made _while_ he was falling, and not, as the movie depicts, immediately before he fell.

Comment: @Josafoot I mean, the rest of the fellowship are not even levelcapped, what good can they be? *(chuckles)*

Comment: @xDaizu - Gandalf strikes me as a loot-hog. Note how he takes the sweet Palantir off of the Hobbit.

Comment: He wasn't near a hundred feet tall in the movie, maybe 20.

Comment: It's worth noting it wasn't over for Gandalf right away. In the book Gandalf and the Balrog fall for what is described as a "very long time" during which both are locked in combat, until they fall to the bottoms of the chasm. Then the balrog flees into a network of tunnels, Gandalf proceeds to pursue it for 8 days and 8 nights. When it finds it they start fighting again and ascend to the summit of a tall mountain, and 2 days later Gandalf finally defeats it and it falls down the mountain, breaking it down. The text is intentionally vague if this was before or after Gandalf's death...

Comment: Also in the book:

The Balrog made no answer. The fire in it seemed to die, but the darkness grew. It stepped forward slowly onto the bridge, and **suddenly it drew itself up to a great height, and its wings were spread from wall to wall**; but still Gandalf could be seen, glimmering in the gloom; he seemed small, and altogether alone: grey and bent, like a wizened tree before the onset of a storm.

Answer (score 37):

Because Gandalf told them not to. When they first encountered the creature, Gandalf tells them

> This is a foe beyond any of you. Run!

And then, when he is hanging on the bridge

> Fly, you fools!

Remember, the orcs were still coming. Time was of the essence.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are referring to the film, I think the best answer is the director's commentary from the writers Peter Jackson, Fran Walsh and Philippa Boyens.

They said that there are a few reasons in this scene. One is that they are actually far away from the bridge and that it had risps and could have been collapsed. Philippa also mentions that there is one scene in the book where Frodo tells Faramir that Aragorn and Boromir had to watch out for them and if they didn't had to, they would not have run away.
Also Fran said that Gandalf with his quote "Fly, you fools!" meant that he let go rather than that he fell. Because he knew it was the decision he was going have to make after the moment he realised the mind of Saruman and his betrayal.

Comment: Can you link to where these quotes can be found? Supporting your argument is important

Comment: @Machavity Is the commentary free online somewhere?

Comment: Sadly I didn't found any site with the commentary. I wanted to write it down but it's hard for me to understand every word.